# The view SugarNoter.views.Index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

Whenever a new user is going to register, after that I get this error, even if I return HttpResponse:

> The view SugarNoter.views.Index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

views.py:

```
def Index(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            passwd = form.clean_password2()
            user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=passwd)
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect(f'users/{str(request.user)}')
    else:
        context = {
            'form':UserCreationForm()
        }
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

html file

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-6 my-5 mx-auto">
        <div class="card align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div class="card-body">
            <form method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{ form | crispy }}
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick='window.location="login"'>Login</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign Up</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not handled the situation when your `form.is_valid()` is false,
In that case you have no return statement.
So you need to return something for else condition too...
Or move the redirect statement out of the if condition...

```
def Index(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            passwd = form.clean_password2()
            user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=passwd)
            auth.login(request, user)
        return redirect(f'users/{str(request.user)}')
    else:
        context = {
            'form':UserCreationForm()
        }
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! for your help